# How can I change Unix timestamp data to MySql timestamps in my database?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am still pretty new to databases in general.

I created one and had my application get the current time as a Unix timestamp and stored in in `time_stamp int(11) NOT NULL`.

Now I realize how dumb that was, but I don't want to lose my data.

Is there an UPDATE statement I can use in the MySql command box to change all those `INT`s to MySql `TIMESTAMP`s?

---

Alternatively, I have a dump of the database, so I guess I could also use PhpMyAdmin to redefine the column (which seems to set all my INTs to "00-00-0000 00:00:00") and then delete the table contents, global edit the SqlDump and import it.

But, if I do, how do I edit the dump?  Here are a few lines of it ...

```sql
INSERT INTO `activity` (`badge_number`, `time_stamp`, `activity`, `bar_code`, `rfid_tag`)   
VALUES (0, 1350388291, 'login', '', ''), (0,1350388433, 'logout', '', ''),
```

So,

```sql
UPDATE ACTIVITY SET time_stamp = <what?> WHERE <what?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either

```sql
ALTER TABLE activity CHANGE time_stamp time_stamp VARCHAR(19);
UPDATE activity 
   SET time_stamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp);
ALTER TABLE activity CHANGE time_stamp time_stamp TIMESTAMP;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31df9/4)** demo

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE activity ADD COLUMN time_stamp2 TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE activity 
   SET time_stamp2 = FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp);
ALTER TABLE activity DROP COLUMN time_stamp;
ALTER TABLE activity CHANGE time_stamp2 time_stamp TIMESTAMP;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da4f1b/1)** demo

**Note:** Before you proceed with update make sure that you have a solid backup of your table/database. Just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this & award the answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate how quickly you answered - and with a demo too!!